# Highcharts solidgauge default tooltip position

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/7cbymps6/

```
    tooltip: {
        positioner: function () {
            if(true) {
                return { 
                    x: this.chart.plotWidth / 1.5,
                    y: this.chart.plotHeight / 2
                };
            } else {
                return {
                  /*x: defaultX ??,
                    y: defaultY ?? */
                };
            }
        }       
    },
```

In else statement I want the tooltip position as it is. But in case of no return statement, it gives error. If I return an empty object, this time it puts the tooltip on the upper left hand side of the chart. How kann I return previous x and y values? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the default position using callback properties: `point`, `labelWidth` and `labelHeight` like that:

```
  tooltip: {
    positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
      if (false) {
        return {
          x: this.chart.plotWidth / 1.5,
          y: this.chart.plotHeight / 2
        };
      } else {
        return {
          x: point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft - labelWidth / 2,
          y: point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop - labelHeight - 10
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jo0eka18/